# catalogue.RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'Custom_Candidate_Gen.v1' in function registry 'misc'

Tags: python-3.x, spacy-3

I am currently building a spacy pipeline with custom NER,Entity Linker and Textcat components. For my Entity Linker component, I have modified the candidate_generator() to suit my use-case. I have used the [ner_emersons](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/nel_emerson) demo project for reference. Following is my custom_functions code.

```
import spacy
from functools import partial
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Callable
from spacy.training import Example
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
from spacy.kb import Candidate, KnowledgeBase, get_candidates

@spacy.registry.misc("Custom_Candidate_Gen.v1")
def create_candidates():
    return custom_get_candidates

def custom_get_candidates(kb, span):
    return kb.get_alias_candidates(span.text.lower())

@spacy.registry.readers("MyCorpus.v1")
def create_docbin_reader(file: Path) -> Callable[["Language"], Iterable[Example]]:
    return partial(read_files, file)


def read_files(file: Path, nlp: "Language") -> Iterable[Example]:
    # we run the full pipeline and not just nlp.make_doc to ensure we have entities and sentences
    # which are needed during training of the entity linker
    with nlp.select_pipes(disable="entity_linker"):
        doc_bin = DocBin().from_disk(file)
        docs = doc_bin.get_docs(nlp.vocab)
        for doc in docs:
            yield Example(nlp(doc.text), doc)
```

After training my entity linker and adding my textcat component to the pipeline, I am getting the following error:

```
catalogue.RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'Custom_Candidate_Gen.v1' in function registry 'misc'. If you're using a custom function, make sure the code is available. If the function is provided by a third-party package, e.g. spacy-transformers, make sure the package is installed in your environment.

Available names: spacy.CandidateGenerator.v1, spacy.EmptyKB.v1, spacy.KBFromFile.v1, spacy.LookupsDataLoader.v1, spacy.ngram_range_suggester.v1, spacy.ngram_suggester.v1
```

Why isn't my custom Candidate Generator getting registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options for having custom code loaded and registered when you load a model:

- import this code directly in your script before loading the model
- package it with your model with `spacy package --code` and load the model from the installed package name (rather than the directory)
- provide this code in a separate package that uses entry points in `setup.cfg` to register the methods (which works fine, but wouldn't be my first choice in this situation)

See: